# mongo no deja acceder una base de datos desde Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, nestjs

Tengo un Backend con Nestjs y quiero conectarlo a una base de datos MongoDB, para esto utilicé docker; de esta forma el código de configuración para el `docker-compose` es el siguiente:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
   ...
```

Por otro lado el codigo de configuración dentro de NestJS es el siguiente en `app.modules.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { CatsModule } from './cats/cats.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://root:example@localhost/'),
    CatsModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Si vamos a cómo se define el `Schema`:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema()
export class Cat {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  breed: string;
}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Como se puede ver es prácticamente el mismo ejemplo que dan desde la documentación oficial. Cuando ejecuto todo va bien hasta que hago una petición al controlador:

```
import { Body, Controller, Post, Put } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
    constructor (private readonly _cat_Service:CatsService){}

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() body){
        await this._cat_Service.create(body);
    }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Cat, CatDocument } from './schemas/cat.schema';

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(Cat.name) private catModel: Model<CatDocument>){}

    async create (create){
        const createCat = new this.catModel(create);
        return createCat.save();
    }
}
```

Todo funciona bien hasta que envío la petición: con esto se me crea una base de datos llamada `tests`; sé que se puede especificar el nombre de la base de datos desde el propio `URI`, quedando algo parecido a lo siguiente : `mongodb://root:example@localhost/prueba-bbdd`, pero al hacer esto pierde la conexión con la base de datos. Intenté crear la base de datos de forma manual pero fue el mismo resultado: no puede conectar si no es con la dirección a `localhost`.

Comment: En la URI que estás usando, hace falta indicar el puerto de conexión. Debería ser así: `mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/prueba-bbdd`. Saludos

Comment: tambien he intentado con el puerto, es decir la conexion en si es perfecta, pero cuando se le dice la base de datos deja de responder, de hecho el resultado sale asi :

Comment: `MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/GG'),`      
`[Nest] 19264  - 26/06/2022, 10:18:32   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...` -- Cabe destacar que si quito la parte de `GG` funciona correctamente

Comment: Encontré un problema similar ya resuelto échale un ojo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730514/unable-to-connect-to-the-database-retrying